# I am not able to get dynamic div id by useRef Reactjs hook as its returning same id repeatedly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I am not able to get dynamic div id by  useRef Reactjs hook as its returning same id repeatedly.i have to use this because i want to map button & div id for making flexible accordion. I want to show only click accordion & rest should be closed, in this way only clicked accordion will be visible.

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Collapse, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import './tabs.scss';

const Tabs = () => {
        const divId = useRef(null);
        const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
        const toggle2 = (index) => {
            let divIdElem = divId,
                divIdElemAttr = divIdElem.current.getAttribute('id')
            console.log('divIdElemAttr', divIdElemAttr)
            if (index === divIdElemAttr) {
                setIsOpen(!isOpen)
            } else {
                setIsOpen(false)
            }
            console.log(index === divIdElem)
        }

        let tabObject2 = [
            {
                tab1: 'tab1 Content'
            },
            {
                tab2: 'tab2 Content'
            },
            {
                tab3: 'tab3 Content'
            }
        ]
        return (
            <>
                <div className="tabBlock">
                    <div className="tab">
                        {
                            tabObject2.map((ds, indexNo) => {
                                console.log(indexNo)
                                return (
                                    <div id={indexNo} ref={divId} key={indexNo} onClick={(indexNo) => toggle2(indexNo)}>
                                        <Button block className="tab-btn-main" >
                                            {Object.keys(ds)}
                                        </Button>

                                        <Collapse isOpen={isOpen}>
                                            <div>
                                                {Object.values(ds)}
                                            </div>
                                        </Collapse>
                                    </div>
                                )
                            })
                        }

                    </div>
                </div>
            </>
        );
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that `const divId = useRef(null);` is creating one ref which is getting used by all the divs inside map function. When you loop, the last div is the one with which ref is finally attached and you get the fixed value for that.
**To fix this, you need to use useRef inside the map function and pass if explicitly to toggle2 function.**

Also, indexNo is passed incorrectly in the code. You are passing event instead of index here.

The fixed code is

```
import React, { useState, useRef } from 'react';
import { Collapse, Button } from 'reactstrap';
import './tabs.scss';

const Tabs = () => {
    //Remove useRef from here
    const [isOpen, setIsOpen] = useState(false);
    //Pass ref explicitly in function instead of directly using it
    const toggle2 = (index, divIdRef) => {
        let divIdElem = divIdRef,
            divIdElemAttr = divIdElem.current.getAttribute('id')
        console.log('divIdElemAttr', divIdElemAttr)
        if (index === divIdElemAttr) {
            setIsOpen(!isOpen)
        } else {
            setIsOpen(false)
        }
        console.log(index === divIdElem)
    }

    let tabObject2 = [
        {
            tab1: 'tab1 Content'
        },
        {
            tab2: 'tab2 Content'
        },
        {
            tab3: 'tab3 Content'
        }
    ]
    return (
        <>
            <div className="tabBlock">
                <div className="tab">
                    {
                        tabObject2.map((ds, indexNo) => {
                            //Use useRef here
                            const divId = useRef(null);
                            console.log(indexNo)
                            return (
                                <div id={indexNo} ref={divId} key={indexNo} onClick={() => toggle2(indexNo, divId)}>
                                    <Button block className="tab-btn-main" >
                                        {Object.keys(ds)}
                                    </Button>

                                    <Collapse isOpen={isOpen}>
                                        <div>
                                            {Object.values(ds)}
                                        </div>
                                    </Collapse>
                                </div>
                            )
                        })
                    }

                </div>
            </div>
        </>
    );
}
```

*You should also avoid using array index for keys and use some other value*

Comment: I think you should change `toggle2(indexNo, divIdRef)` to `toggle2(indexNo, divId)`,am i right?